# I want to assign id into var but nothing display

Tags: javascript, html

Firstly. i am a beginner. 
I want to display total that showed in read only text box into the proper looking box. This is my coding.

This is the text box and it shows value succesfully.

```
<input  name="total" value="" id= "TOTAL" readonly/>
```

Now i want to display it here but it won't

```
var displayTotal = document.getElementById('TOTAL').value;

divobj.innerHTML = "Your Total Price is RM"+displayTotal ;
```

Please help me and thank you!!

Comment: What is `divobj`?  When does this code run, before or after a value is entered?  This otherwise works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0rj2cqLh/

Comment: Check the console for any errors and add them here and/or add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: I have value in my html as I type number in the other box. it display total.

Comment: @Wan: Then what isn't working about this?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, how specifically does this first fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's `divobj` ? I've never seen it. What you could try is targeting a div's id

```
var displayTotal = document.getElementById('TOTAL').value;

document.forms["formsID"]["targetID"].innerHTML = "Your Total Price is RM"+displayTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

the first issue is that you never declare a var that using the TOTAL element as element (you catch  the value too soon :))

second - what is that divobj? its point nothing.

the third issue is that your trying to push innerHTML into Input element.

so the proper way to do what you looking for is:

```
var displayTotal = document.getElementById('TOTAL')
displayTotal.value = "Your Total Price is RM "+displayTotal.value ;
```

your head start was fairly good! keep going and good luck

Comment: Thanks for helping. but i tried copy your solution and it's add the text everytime i press radio button. but i will figure it out. thanks again.

Comment: to do such event you need to create a function that response to your change-event